# How do I mock a specific function from a module for a specific test (Jest)

Tags: testing, jestjs

I have an api.js file that contains my api call.  It looks like this:

```
// api.js

// reusable fetch call
export const makeFetch = async (url, options) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`${response.status}`);
    }

    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Network request failed. (error: ${error.message})`);
  }
};

// actual fetch call
export const getCards = async () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/cards';
  return await makeFetch(url);
};
```

Then I have an api.test.js file that looks like:

```
//api.test.js

import { makeFetch, getCards } from './api';

describe('makeFetch', () => {

  // three successful tests

});

// this is where I have issues

describe('getCards', () => {
  it('calls makeFetch', async () => {

    await getCards();

    expect(makeFetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

this is the error I get:

```
FAIL  src\api\api.test.js
  ● getCards › calls makeFetch

    ReferenceError: makeFetch is not defined

      at Object.it.only (src/api/api.test.js:51:15)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
          at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
```

Does anyone know how to make this pass with making my previous tests fail?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a mock of makeFetch.  You can do that using [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) and [mockReturnValue](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvaluevalue).

You will need to move makeFetch into its own file (lib.js) so that you can mock and replace it in your test:

```
// ---- lib.js ----
// reusable fetch call
export const makeFetch = async (url, options) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`${response.status}`);
    }

    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Network request failed. (error: ${error.message})`);
  }
};



// ---- api.js ----
import { makeFetch } from './lib';

// actual fetch call
export const getCards = async () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/cards';
  return await makeFetch(url);
};



// ---- api.test.js ----
import * as lib from './lib';
import { getCards } from './api';

describe('makeFetch', () => {

  // three successful tests

});

describe('getCards', () => {
  it('calls makeFetch', async () => {
    const simulatedResponse = { data: 'simulated response' };

    // mock makeFetch
    const mock = jest.spyOn(lib, 'makeFetch');
    mock.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(simulatedResponse));

    const result = await getCards();

    expect(result).toEqual(simulatedResponse);
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/cards');

    // restore makeFetch
    mock.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but when running this, it fails due to:
"TypeError: mock.mockResolvedValue is not a function"

If I change that line to:
"mock.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(simulatedResponse));"

The test response becomes: 
Expected value to equal:
      {"data": "simulated response"}
    Received:
      [[Object], [Object], ...]

Comment: Ah, you're using an earlier version of Jest, I'll update my answer in a minute

Comment: That works! You are the best.  I am using create-react-app so I guess the version of jest included is old.  Thank you very much for your help

Comment: my pleasure, glad it helped

Comment: Opps, thanks.  Done. (I upvoted but it wont show because I have < 15 reputation)